# Continent - creating a new variable - R

Tags: r

I have 198 countries, named by the UN, in my data frame. I want to create a new variable that divides these countries in continents.

I have been using the following code so far:

```
attach(df) 
df$Continent[Country==c('country', 'country', ...)] <- "Americas"
df$Continent[Country==c('country', 'country', ...)] <- "Africa"
df$Continent[Country==c('country', 'country', ...)] <- "Asia"
df$Continent[Country==c('country', 'country', ...)] <- "Europe"
df$Continent[Country==c('country', 'country', ...)] <- "Oceania"
detach(df)
```

The problem is that R doesn't let me put all the country names available for each continent in the same bracket, displaying the warning message “longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length”. If I separate the countries in multiple lines, I can make it. However, this is quite inefficient, so I wonder if there is a clever/quickest way to do it?

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1):

As [LyzandeR stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698958/continent-creating-a-new-variable-r#comment82357945_47698958), you can use the `%in%` operator. It may also be cleaner to define the list of countries first, like so:

```
americas <- c("country", "country", "country", ...)
africa <- c("country", "country", "country", ...)
asia <- c("country", "country", "country", ...)
# and so on...

attach(df) 
df$Continent[Country %in% americas] <- "Americas"
df$Continent[Country %in% africa] <- "Africa"
df$Continent[Country %in% asia] <- "Asia"
df$Continent[Country %in% europe] <- "Europe"
df$Continent[Country %in% oceania] <- "Oceania"
detach(df)
```